# How can I get the maximum date of both passed and failed results using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I need a SQL query from the below:

**Table**: user_results

| id | cId | uId | tId | pass | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 34 | 2 | Y | 7/8/2013 10:24:47 |
| 2 | 23 | 34 | 2 | N | 11/27/2014 10:36:32 |
| 3 | 23 | 34 | 3 | Y | 12/9/2013 10:24:47 |
| 4 | 23 | 34 | 3 | N | 11/27/2014 10:39:10 |
| 5 | 23 | 34 | 4 | Y | 10/26/2013 10:24:47 |
| 6 | 23 | 34 | 4 | N | 11/27/2014 10:38:08 |
| 7 | 59 | 93 | 2 | Y | 11/24/2013 9:34:23 |
| 8 | 69 | 82 | 2 | Y | 11/28/2014 9:04:22 |
| 9 | 69 | 82 | 2 | Y | 11/28/2014 8:59:52 |
| 10 | 69 | 82 | 4 | Y | 11/28/2014 8:59:52 |
| 11 | 69 | 82 | 4 | Y | 11/28/2014 9:10:40 |
| 12 | 69 | 82 | 4 | N | 11/28/2014 9:12:01 |
| 13 | 72 | 72 | 2 | N | 12/1/2014 6:46:02 |
| 14 | 73 | 69 | 2 | N | 12/1/2014 6:49:29 |
| 15 | 73 | 69 | 3 | N | 12/1/2014 6:51:31 |
| 16 | 73 | 69 | 3 | N | 12/1/2014 7:11:25 |

Below one is the expected results:

| id | cId | uId | tId | pass | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 34 | 2 | Y | 7/8/2013 10:24:47 |
| 3 | 23 | 34 | 3 | Y | 12/9/2013 10:24:47 |
| 5 | 23 | 34 | 4 | Y | 10/26/2013 10:24:47 |
| 7 | 59 | 93 | 2 | Y | 11/24/2013 9:34:23 |
| 9 | 69 | 82 | 2 | Y | 11/28/2014 8:59:52 |
| 11 | 69 | 82 | 4 | Y | 11/28/2014 9:10:40 |
| 13 | 72 | 72 | 2 | N | 12/1/2014 6:46:02 |
| 14 | 73 | 69 | 2 | N | 12/1/2014 6:49:29 |
| 16 | 73 | 69 | 3 | N | 12/1/2014 7:11:25 |

**Note:** If User passed the tests(# of attempts), need to show the recent pass entries and If User failed the tests(# of attempts), need to show the recent fail entries.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(tId), MAX(date)
FROM user_results
WHERE DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR )
GROUP BY cId, tId
HAVING COUNT(tId) =1 OR (pass = 'Y' AND COUNT(tId) >=2)
```

Comment: do you mean you want recent pass and recent fail entries

Comment: Yes, Sunil. i want to show the recent pass and recent fail entries.

Comment: have you tried using `ORDER BY` on your results?

Comment: Try this 'ORDER BY date DESC'

Comment: Yes, I tried with 'ORDER BY date DESC'. But I didn't get the expected results, the output results are showing in descending order.

Comment: Note that dates in mysql adhere to a specific format. Deviation from that format does not aid clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with the following query,

1) You have to add the failed cases in HAVING clause and will get the both pass and fail results.

2) Concat the pass and date column with '@' separator and will get the value: Y@7/8/2013 10:24:47

3) Sorting with this value you will get the recent pass and recent fail.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(tId), MAX(date), 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(CONCAT(pass, '@', date)), '@', -1) AS max_date, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(MAX(CONCAT(pass, '@', date)), '@', 1) AS pass_stat
FROM user_results
WHERE DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR )
GROUP BY cId, tId
HAVING COUNT(tId) =1 OR (pass = 'Y' AND COUNT(tId) >=2) OR (pass = 'N' AND COUNT(tId) >=2)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
select cid, tid, max(date) as max_date 
from user_results where pass = 'Y' group by cId, tId
```

gives you all users, that have passed the exam and the latest date. Because we need to group by cid, tid, we have to exlude the id. To get the right id to our "final" result we just make a join with the original user_results_table with:

```
select r.* from user_results r join 
   (select cid, tid, max(date) as max_date 
   from user_results where pass = 'Y' group by cId, tId) t on 
(r.cId = t.cId and r.tId = t.tId and r.date = t.max_date)
```

Now you have all users that have passed the exam with the latest date and all the additional information like id and uId.

The next step is, to include all those users, that failed an exam and the latest date. Similar to the first query above, the following query

```
select r1.cId, r1.tId, max(r1.date) as max_date 
from user_results r1 
where r1.pass = 'N' 
group by r1.cId, r1.tId
```

will give you all users that failed an exam and the latest date. But the problem with this query is, that it includes every user that has failed an exam, which means that users, that have passed the exam also gets included. Therefore we need to exlude those users who already have passed an exam by adding (for example) a not exists statement

```
select r1.cId, r1.tId, max(r1.date) as max_date 
from user_results r1 
where r1.pass = 'N' and not exists 
      (select * from user_results r2  
       where r2.pass = 'Y' and r2.cId = r1.cId and r2.tId = r1.tId)
group by r1.cId, r1.tId
```

Like above we then join this result with the user_results table to get all the additional information:

```
select r.*
from user_results r join 
     (select r1.cId, r1.tId, max(r1.date) as max_date 
      from user_results r1 
      where r1.pass = 'N' and not exists 
      (select * from user_results r2  
       where r2.pass = 'Y' and r2.cId = r1.cId and r2.tId = r1.tId)
     group by r1.cId, r1.tId) t on 
(r.cId = t.cId and r.tId = t.tId and r.date = t.max_date)
```

And finally we "merge" these to result-queries (the query for those users who have passed the exam and the query for those who have failed) with the union-operator. So the final query is:

```
select r.*
from user_results r join 
     (select cid, tid, max(date) as max_date 
      from user_results where pass = 'Y' group by cId, tId) t on 
(r.cId = t.cId and r.tId = t.tId and r.date = t.max_date)
union
select r.*
from user_results r join 
     (select r1.cId, r1.tId, max(r1.date) as max_date 
      from user_results r1 
      where r1.pass = 'N' and not exists 
      (select * from user_results r2  
       where r2.pass = 'Y' and r2.cId = r1.cId and r2.tId = r1.tId)
     group by r1.cId, r1.tId) t on 
(r.cId = t.cId and r.tId = t.tId and r.date = t.max_date)
```

This should work. I've tested it and couldn't notice any failures.

Comment: Thank you so much, Iris! Its very clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.cId, a.uId, a.tI, a.pass, a.date 
FROM tableA a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.cId, a.uId, a.tId, MAX(a.date) maxDate 
            FROM tableA 
            GROUP BY a.cId, a.uId, a.tId
          ) b ON a.cId = b.cId AND a.uId = b.uId AND a.tId = c.tId AND a.date = b.maxDate
```

Comment: I need a recent pass and recent fail entries from the results. But in your query, its showing recent record only. Please check with my expected results.

Answer (score 0):

i thin this is more simple and working fine

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * 
FROM user_results
WHERE DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR )
GROUP BY cId, tId
ORDER BY date) 
AS a
ORDER BY CID, tid
```